# How to remove leading '0's from HH:MM:SS?

Tags: php

I have a function which converts seconds to the format of Hours:Minutes:Seconds

```
  function sec2hms ($sec) 
  {
    $hms = "";

    $hours = intval(intval($sec) / 3600); 
    $minutes = intval(($sec / 60) % 60); 
    $seconds = intval($sec % 60); 

    $hms .= str_pad($hours, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT). ":";        
    $hms .= str_pad($minutes, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT). ":";    
    $hms .= str_pad($seconds, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

    return $hms;    
  }
```

How can I change this function so that all leading digits beyond the first minute position will be stripped?

For example

```
sec2hms(9) //returns 0:09
sec2hms(123) //returns 2:03
sec2hms(5941)//returns 1:39:01
```

Comment: You should simply use a if statement...

Comment: You know you are in fact placing the "unwanted 0" by using str_pad() funcion?

Comment: I've heard of write-only code, but did you even *try*?

Comment: What does write-only code mean?

Comment: Discrepancy in title (_"strip leading 0's"_) and actual problem/question (_"strip leading hour part if 0 and leading 0 on minute if there isn't an hour part"_) causes confusion I see....

Comment: You wrote the code, but you cannot read and understand what it does, making it impossible for you to make changes to it yourself. That's write-only code. Also, if the input is an hour and two minutes, do you really want it to print "1:2:00"? I doubt it.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy No, I don't, See the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the function I just wrote

```
function secondsToHHMMSS ($sec) 
{
    $hms = "";

    $hours = intval(intval($sec) / 3600); 
    $minutes = intval(($sec / 60) % 60); 
    $seconds = intval($sec % 60); 


    if($hours != 0){
    $hms .=  $hours . ":";
    $hms .=  str_pad($minutes, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . ":";        
    $hms .= str_pad($seconds, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
    else{
    $hms .= $minutes . ":";
    $hms .= str_pad($seconds, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }

    return $hms;    
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply don't use [str_pad()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) function on minutes. It's adding leading zeros.

Answer (score 3):

```
  function sec2hms ($sec) 
  {
    $hms = "";

    $hours = intval(intval($sec) / 3600); 
    $minutes = intval(($sec / 60) % 60); 
    $seconds = intval($sec % 60); 

    if($hours)
        $hms .= $hours. ":";        
    $hms .= $minutes. ":";    
    $hms .= str_pad($seconds, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

    return $hms;    
  }
```

Comment: @LedZeppelin Try calling `sec2hms(3720)`: didn't you just say in your comments that this was undesirable?

Answer (score 2):

You have in the own code.

The function str_pad fill 0 on the left side.
Just take out that function.

```
$hms = $hours.':'.$minutes.':'.$seconds;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try returning this, instead:

```
return ltrim(substr($hms, 0, 4), ':0').substr($hms, 4);
```